# What is the better approach to call commerce server profile refresh method?

Tags: c#, microsoft-commerce-server

I get the profile objects for customer,contact,phone,address and then i call profile refresh method after each time i get these profile objects. The app is deployed on a web farm.

I find performance lag with my current approach. We are currently limited to use commerce server 2007.

What is the better approach to call commerce server profile refresh method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The recommended approach is documented in [Using Profiles in a Web Farm Scenario](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb219221%28v=cs.70%29.aspx)